# Remove and zip files in directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

DIRECTORY=/main/dir/sub-dir

if [ -d $DIRECTORY ]; then
      find $DIRECTORY/ '*' -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;;
#Zip Files generated within the last six hour
      find $DIRECTORY/ '*' -maxdepth 1 -mmin -360 -exec gzip {} \;
   fi

I'm using this command to remove files generated within the last , however the output has the following errors


Error messages :

-bash-4.2$ ./zip_files.sh
find: â*â: No such file or directory
gzip: /main/dir/sub-dir is a directory -- ignored


Files in this directory will be of these sequence, 

-rw------- 1 postgres dba 16777216 Sep 23 23:37 000000010000224300000015
-rw------- 1 postgres dba 16777216 Sep 23 23:37 000000010000224300000016
-rw------- 1 postgres dba 16777216 Sep 23 23:37 000000010000224300000017
-rw------- 1 postgres dba 16777216 Sep 23 23:37 000000010000224300000018
-rw------- 1 postgres dba 16777216 Sep 23 23:37 000000010000224300000019
-rw------- 1 postgres dba 16777216 Sep 23 23:37 00000001000022430000001A
```

i only want to remove the files removed and gzipped and compress the Error messages

Appreciate your response in replying back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script could look like the following. Note the *quotes*, note the usage of *unquoted* `*` *without a space*, note the `find` arguments, see `man find`. Check your script with shellcheck!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# prefer upper case variables only for exported variables
directory=/main/dir/sub-dir
if [[ -d "$directory" ]]; then
      find "$directory"/* -maxdepth 1 -type f \
          '(' -mtime +1 -delete ')' -o \
          '(' -mmin -360 -exec gzip {} ';' ')'
fi
```

With bash arrays you can put comments between long argument lines:

```
      cmd=(
          find "$directory"/* -maxdepth 1 -type f
          # delete somthing
          '(' -mtime +1 -delete ')' -o
          # gzip them
          '(' -mmin -360 -exec gzip {} ';' ')'
      )
      "${cmd[@]}"
```